# xslt Transformation of xml that contains special characters in the data like &

Tags: xslt

I have seen posts that explain how to output an actual `&` but my problem is on the input side. I have data coming out of the database (Oracle) into a `DataSet.DataTable` and yes we do perform a `datatable.WriteXml` which produces the xml structure I am looking for.

I have tried all the suggested methods for encoding the writer (xml and / or string) before I writeXml into it but the `&` persists.

I then need to pass this xml representation of the dataset through an xslt transformation and it fails when I hit the special character `&`.

What's my solution. It's gotta be something simple. I was thinking there could be some xsl setting on the xslt transformation that would handle this for me?

Comment: Please provide the input XML or relevant extract, XSLT portion that fails and what sort of error you're getting.

Comment: & needs to be converted into &amp; when inside your xml - normally this escaping should be the job of tool you are using to construct your xml. When the &amp; is read in by your xml parser, it should see just & in it's internal structures.

Answer (score 0):

```
  &amp; is an entity ...
  &#x26; is the numeric value of the symbol in utf-8
```

If you use escape sequences (with the #) you can never fail interpretation, but you can pick a wrong numeric value though.